# ¿Por qué cuando envio el formulario se guarda dos veces en django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

El formulario almacena datos:
**autor** que es llave foránea, **titulo**, **contenido** y tres llaves foráneas de **etiquetas**.

Cuando los campos del formulario están llenos, se envía y se almacena dos veces.
La primera vez que guarda los datos del formulario, los almacena todos, y la segunda vez solo guarda los datos de autor, titulo y contenido.

[image: Panel Administrador]

El código de la vista (views) para almacenar los datos es el siguiente:

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
model = Proyecto
form_class = ProjectForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('projects:projects')

def post(self,request):
    form_class = ProjectForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = Proyecto()
            #form.instance.FK_autor = self.request.user
            try:
                pro = form.save(commit=False)
                pro.FK_autor = request.user
                a = form.instance.FK_autor
                print('A: ', str(a))
                project.FK_autor = a
                

                title = str(form.cleaned_data['titulo'])
                project.titulo = title
                
                content = str(form.cleaned_data['contenido'])
                project.contenido = content

                tag_uno = str(form.cleaned_data['tag_uno'])
                print('tag_uno: ', tag_uno)
                t1= Etiqueta_uno(tag = tag_uno)
                t1.save()
                project.FK_tag_uno = t1

                tag_dos = str(form.cleaned_data['tag_dos'])
                print('tag_dos: ', tag_dos)
                t2= Etiqueta_dos(tag = tag_dos)
                t2.save()
                project.FK_tag_dos = t2

                tag_tres = str(form.cleaned_data['tag_tres'])
                print('tag_tres: ', tag_tres)
                t3= Etiqueta_tres(tag = tag_tres)
                t3.save()
                project.FK_tag_tres = t3

                project.save()
                pro.save()
            except:
                print('error')

            
            
        return self.form_valid(form)
    return self.form_invalid(form)
```

El código del form:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
tag_uno = forms.CharField(help_text='Primera especie')
tag_dos = forms.CharField(help_text='Segunda especie')
tag_tres = forms.CharField(help_text='Tercera especie')

class Meta:
    model = Proyecto
    fields = ['titulo','contenido','tag_uno','tag_dos','tag_tres']
    widgets = {
        'titulo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Titulo'}),
        'contenido': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Contenido', 'rows':3}),
    }
```

Resultado del primer almacenado:

[image: first-save]

Resultados del segundo almacenado:

[image: second-save]

Solo me interesa almacenar una sola vez los datos, como en la imagen de la primera vez que se almacena.

¡Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es esta linea:

```
return self.form_valid(form)
```

Dicho método se encarga de crear el objeto si el formulario esta valido y redireccionar a la URL exitosa, tu lo que haces es crear el objeto "manualmente" y posteriormente llamas al método `form_valid`, y se crea otro objeto, creándose así "2 objetos". Y esa es una de las razones del porque el segundo objeto no tiene etiquetas.

> Por otra parte al momento de crear el objeto "manualmente"(en el
> método `post`), o esas "cosas"... haces barbaridades xD, pues estas
> creando **2 objetos mas**:
>
> ```
> ...
> project = Proyecto() # creas un objeto
> pro = form.save(commit=False) # creas un objeto
> pro.FK_autor = request.user
> a = form.instance.FK_autor # no se que carajos haces XDD
> project.FK_autor = a
> ...
> project.save() # guardas el objeto
> pro.save() # guardas el objeto
> ```
>
> Y en total se crean como 4 objetos o algo asi, pero bueno, tu método `post` debería
> ser así:
>
> ```
> def post(self,request):
>     if request.method == 'POST':
>         form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
>         if form.is_valid():
>             form.instance.FK_autor = request.user
>             
>             # --- Etiqueta uno ---
>             t1 = Etiqueta_uno(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_uno'])
>             t1.save()
>
>             form.instance.FK_tag_uno = t1
>
>             # -- Etiqueta dos ---
>             t2 = Etiqueta_dos(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_dos'])
>             t2.save()
>
>             form.instance.FK_tag_dos = t2
>
>             # --- Etiqueta tres ---
>             t3 = Etiqueta_tres(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_tres'])
>             t3.save()
>
>             form.instance.FK_tag_tres = t3
>             
>             # --- Guardamos el objeto ---
>             form.save() 
>             
>             return redirect(self.get_success_url())
>         else:
>             return self.form_invalid(form)
> ```

Eso solucionaría tu problema.
Por otra parte, lo que te recomiendo es un `ModelAdmin` personalizado:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ... import ProjectForm

@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProjectForm

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            obj.FK_autor = request.user
                
            # --- Etiqueta uno ---
            t1 = Etiqueta_uno(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_uno'])
            t1.save()

            obj.FK_tag_uno = t1

            # -- Etiqueta dos ---
            t2 = Etiqueta_dos(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_dos'])
            t2.save()

            obj.FK_tag_dos = t2

            # --- Etiqueta tres ---
            t3 = Etiqueta_tres(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_tres'])
            t3.save()

            obj.FK_tag_tres = t3
        
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

---

Por otra parte, veo que tratas los modelos como "registros", lo cual esta mal, deberías crear un solo modelo llamado `Etiqueta` :

```
class Etiqueta(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    proyecto = models.ForeignKey(Proyecto, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.especie
```

De esta manera una etiqueta puede tener solo un proyecto y un proyecto varias etiquetas.

Y creas de la siguiente manera los objetos en el método `post`:

```
...
if form.is_valid():
    form.instance.FK_autor = request.user
    proyecto = form.save()

    Etiqueta.objects.bulk_create([
        Etiqueta(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_uno'], proyecto = proyecto),
        Etiqueta(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_dos'], proyecto = proyecto),
        Etiqueta(tag = form.cleaned_data['tag_tres'], proyecto = proyecto),
    ])
else:
    ...
```

Y podrás acceder a las etiquetas de la siguiente manera:

> ```
> >>> p = Proyecto.objects.get(...)
> >>> p.etiqueta_set.all()
> <QuerySet: [...]> # Etiquetas relacionadas
> ```
>
> Y viceversa:
>
> ```
> >>> e = Etiqueta.objects.get(...)
> >>> e.proyecto
> <Proyecto: ...>
> ```

Y listo eso seria todo, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio!
Me ayudaste bastante..
Tienes razón con lo de los registros...
Haré modificaciones gracias!

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)